# Parsing webhook notification using Java

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-webhooks

From the Java SDK code examples, I could only find how to validate a received webhook event.

Anyone knows how to parse received **HTTP request body** posted by PayPal to my webhook handler servlet into an **Event** object?

I initially figured sth like that, which seems clumsy:

```
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject o = parser.parse(requestBody).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonElement idAsJsonObject = o.get("id");
        String id = idAsJsonObject.getAsString();
        Event event = Event.get(apiContextStore.create(), id);
```

*Context: I want to use Payments API in asynchronous mode to move funds from our PayPal account to customer's PayPal account. I am creating a handler for the Webhook notifications to move the payment into completed state on our side.*